# Counting common nodes between two nodes with igraph in R

Tags: r, nodes, igraph

Suppose I've generated an undirected graph(you can think about the graph of my friends on facebook). I would like to know, for each couple of nodes(taken two friends), the number of common "nodes" they have(the "mutual friends" of them). Is there a function in igraph that I can use?

Or in network or sna packages?

Thank you.

Comment: See `cocitation()` or `bibcoupling()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If v_1 and v_2 are the two nodes in the graph g, then:

```
cocitation(g, v_1)[v_2]
```

will give you the number of "mutual friends" they have.
Obviously is the same of

```
cocitation(g, v_2)[v_1]
```